# What is the advantage of sequential mining patterns over apriori algorithm?

Tags: data-mining

I mean is it only that sequence patterns algorithms like aprioriall gives an order to the items? Can this maybe reduce the number of association rules?

Comment: apriori vs aprioriall ??? it is posible to compare??

Answer (score 5):

**Frequent Itemset mining** (FIM) algorithms such as Apriori takes as input a transaction database. A transaction is just a set of items without any ordering.  The goal is to find sets of items that appear often in transactions, without considering a sequential ordering such as time.

**Sequential pattern mining** (SPM) algorithms such as AprioriAll, PrefixSpan, CM-SPADE and GSP takes as input a sequence database. A sequence is an ordered list of transactions. The goal is to discover subsequences that appear often in a set of sequences.  In that case, the sequential ordering between items is considered.

Thus, you should use sequential pattern mining instead of frequent itemset mining if there is a sequential ordering in your data or if you care about the order in the result. If you don't care about the ordering, you may use a FIM algorithm.

Besides, I notice that you also talk about **association rules**. Let me clarify those ideas. Frequent itemsets can be used to generate association rules. A rule X --> Y between two sets of items means that items in X appears with items in Y with a given confidence and support. But association rules does not provide any information about whether there is a sequential ordering between X and Y.   If you want to find rules with a sequential ordering, you should consider using **sequential rules** instead.  Sequential rules can be found directly by some algorithm or may be derived from sequential patterns.

What is the difference between a sequential rule and a sequential pattern?  Sequential patterns are usually found based on their support (in how many sequences they appear in a sequence database).  A sequential rule on the other hand is usually found based on its support and confidence, and is thus more useful for applications such as recommendation. The confidence of a rule X ->Y can be viewed as an estimation of the probability that Y will follows X.

If you want to try some FIM, SPM and sequential rule mining algorithms, you may visit the website of the [SPMF data mining library](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/) (i'm the founder) which offer more than 200 algorithm implementations for these problems with some examples, as well.

Comment: Omfg! I just checked you library, it is awesome! I was looking for something similar for 2-3 months, it could have spared a massive amount of time for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn temporal/sequential behavior, you must not discard this part of your information, but integrate it in your algorithm.

I.e. if you want to learn *sets*, use APRIORI. If you want to learn *sequences*, use sequential approaches.

Comment: It does not make sense to compare Apriori and AprioriALL in terms of performance.  These two algorithms have similar ideas (they are based on the idea of generating candidates in a level-wise manner). However, they do not take the same input and do not produce the same output.

Comment: Another comment: The term "temporal" refers to time. It is better to use the term "sequential ordering" instead of the term "temporal" when talking about sequential patterns because they may also be applied on sequence of items not related to time such as sequences of words in a text.